# Too many if else statements

Tags: powershell

I am trying to check if a string "03-22-2019" exists (or not and show the result in output)  the file is of ".sql" or ".txt" .

```
execution\development\process.sql
insert.sql
production\logs.txt
restore.sql
rebuild.txt
```

I am trying below code but I did with too many `if else`. The above file path stored in the `$paths` variable. I need to split the path with "\" and get the last part of the path to do something else.

```cs
if ($paths -like "*.sql") {
    if ($paths.Contains("\")) {
        $last = $paths.Split("\")[-1] #get the last part of the path
        $result = "03-22-2019" #get this date from some where else
        if ($result) {
            #check if pattern string exists in that file.
            $SEL = Select-String -Path <path location> -Pattern $result
            if ($SEL -ne $null) {
                Write-Host "`n $last Contains Matching date "
            } else {
                Write-Host "`n $last Does not Contains date"
            }
        } else {
            Write-Host "`ndate field is blank"
        }
    } else {
        $result = "03-22-2019" #get this date from some where else
        if ($result) {
            #check if pattern string exists in that file.
            $SEL = Select-String -Path <path location> -Pattern $result
            if ($SEL -ne $null) {
                Write-Host "`n $last Contains Matching date "
            } else {
                Write-Host "`n $last Does not Contains date"
            }
        } else {
            Write-Host "`ndate field is blank"
        }
    }
} elseIf ($paths -like "*.txt") {
    if ($paths.Contains("\")) {
        $last = $paths.Split("\")[-1] #get the last part of the path
        $result = "03-22-2019" #get this date from some where else
        if ($result) {
            #check if pattern string exists in that file.
            $SEL = Select-String -Path <path location> -Pattern $result
            if ($SEL -ne $null) {
                Write-Host "`n $last Contains Matching date "
            } else {
                Write-Host "`n $last Does not Contains date"
            }
        } else {
            Write-Host "`ndate field is blank"
        }
    } else {
        $result = "03-22-2019" #get this date from some where else
        if ($result) {
            #check if pattern string exists in that file.
            $SEL = Select-String -Path <path location> -Pattern $result
            if ($SEL -ne $null) {
                Write-Host "`n $last Contains Matching date "
            } else {
                Write-Host "`n $last Does not Contains date"
            }
        } else {
            Write-Host "`ndate field is blank"
        }
    }
} else {
    Write-Host "other file types"
}
```

Comment: If you obtain the path via Get-Item/Get-ChildItem you should directly check the properties `Name/BaseName/Extension` and probaply use a `switch` instead of that bunch of `if/elseif/else`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would make this a little simpler, below is an example to determine if a file contains the date:

```
$paths = @("c:\path1","c:\path2\subdir")
ForEach ($path in $paths) {
    $files = Get-ChildItem -LiteralPath $path -file -include "*.sql","*.txt"
    $last = ($path -split "\\")[-1] # contains the last part of the path
    $output = ForEach ($file in $files) {
        If (Select-String -path $file -pattern "03-22-2019") {
        "$($file.fullname) contains the date."
        }
        else {
        "$($file.fullname) does not contain the date."
        }
    }
}

$output # outputs whether or not a file has the date string
```

The outer `ForEach` loop loops through the paths in `$paths`. Inside of that loop, you can do what you need to each path `$path`. I used `$last` to store the last part of the path in the current iteration. You have not said what to do with that.

The inner `ForEach` checks each **.txt** and **.sql** file for the date text 03-22-2019. `$output` stores a string indicating whether each **.txt** and **.sql** file contains the date string.

If your paths contain the file names, then you can use the following alternatives to grab the file name (last part of the path):

```
$path | split-path -leaf # inside of the outer ForEach loop
# Or
$file.name # inside of the inner ForEach loop
```

Comment: $($file.fullname) is this the same as $file.name?if they are different whats the difference

Comment: `$file.fullname` displays the complete path of the file name, e.g. `R:\Folder\File.csv`. `$file.name` shows only the file name, e.g. `File.csv`.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you should start with a foreach after your $paths variable like this:

```
foreach ($path in $paths) {
    if ($path -like "*.sql") {    #Note the use of one single item in the $paths array you have
        $last = $path.split("\")[-1]
        $result = #Whatever method you want to use to return a DateTime object
        if ($result) { #### Now, this line doesn't make any sense. Do you want to compare a date to an older date or something? Maybe something like "if ($result -ge (Get-Date).addDays(-1) )
        { # Do your stuff }
```

Doing something like:

```
if ($paths -like "*.sql")
```

Doesn't work because $paths is an array and you are making a string comparison and never the two shall meet. Now, if you are trying to find if a string is inside a file, you should use something like "Get-Content" or "Import-Csv"

You can use the "Get-Date" cmdlet to get many different formats for the date. Read about that [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-date?view=powershell-6). If you are trying to compare multiple dates against multiple files, I would start with a for loop on the files like I did up there, and then a for loop *on each file* for an array of dates. Maybe something like this:

```
foreach ($path in $paths) {
    foreach ($date in $dates) { 
        # Get the contents of a file and store it in a variable
        # Search for the string in that variable and store the results in a variable
        # Write to the console
    } # End foreach ($date in $dates)
} # End foreach ($path in $paths)
```

Post some more updated code and let's see what you come up with.